# Compare 2 different columns of different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes let's say->

df1 =>

```
colA  colB  colC
0     1     2   
3     4     5 
6     7     8
```

df2 (same number of rows and columns) =>

```
colD  colE  colF
10     11     12    
13     14     15  
16     17     18
```

I want to compare columns from both dataframes , example ->

```
df1['colB'] < df2['colF']
```

Currently I am getting ->

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

while comparing in ->

**EDIT** :

```
df1.loc[

    df1['colB'] < df2['colF']

],'set_something' = 1;
```

Any help how I can implement it ? Thanks

Comment: The error is due to the fact that your `dfs` have different indices. Either set the same index (check, e.g. `.reset_index(drop=True)`), or turn one of the two into an array (`.to_numpy()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the error because your series are not aligned (and might have duplicated indices)

If you just care about position, not indices use the underlying nummy array:

```
df1['colB'] < df2['colF'].to_numpy()
```

If you want to assign back in a column, make sure to transform the column full the **other** DataFrame to array.

```
df1['new'] = df1['colB'] < df2['colF'].to_numpy()
```

Or

```
df2['new'] = df1['colB'].to_numpy() < df2['colF']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-equi join; you should get more performance with some of binary search; [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) does that under the hood:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df1.conditional_join(df2, ('colB', 'colF', '<')) 
   colA  colB  colC  colD  colE  colF
0     0     1     2    10    11    12
1     0     1     2    13    14    15
2     0     1     2    16    17    18
3     3     4     5    10    11    12
4     3     4     5    13    14    15
5     3     4     5    16    17    18
6     6     7     8    10    11    12
7     6     7     8    13    14    15
8     6     7     8    16    17    18
```

If it is based on an equality (`df1.colB == df2.colF`), then `pd.merge` should suffice and is efficient